# Include associated products when checking if product is discounted to show sales tag in list

Tags: magento-1.9, associated-products

I'm currently showing a sale tag on products that are discounted in list.phtml:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
$specialprice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSpecialPrice(); 
$special_from_date = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
$special_to_date = $_product->getSpecialToDate();

<?php if (($specialprice && ($special_from_date <= $now) && ($special_to_date >= $now || $special_to_date =="" ))) { ?>
    <div class='sale-item'>
        <span class="text">
            <?php echo $this->__('Sale') ?>
        </span>
    </div>
<?php } endif; ?>
```

This works well, however if a product is a grouped product type and one of it's associated products is discounted, the sale tag does not show so I somehow need to include associated products when checking if the product is discounted.

The list template is just using the default loaded collection currently:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)
```

I believe I can get any associated products with the following?

```
$associatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product);
```

Not quite sure how the best way of working this into the checking of whether the product is discounted or not though...

Comment: Check answers & give feedback

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this in a helper

```
public function isSale($product)
{
    if ($product->isGrouped()){
        foreach ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product) as $childProduct){
            if ($childProduct->getFinalPrice() < $childProduct->getPrice()){
                // if at least one child is "on sale", then parent is flagged
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will check **catalogrule** discounts too, not only **special_price**. If you want to check just special_price, then you'd include that date from & to validations